# scroll top is not working when using smooth scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am working on form step template. i have to start scroll from top when i click on "Save and continue" button but its not working but when i remove smooth scrolling code it works,what should i do

this code for scroll top

```
<script type="text/javascript">     
    $(".next-step").click(function(){
         $(window).scrollTop(0);
    });    
</script>
```

this code for smooth scroll

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
  // Add smooth scrolling to all links
  $("a").on('click', function(event) {

    // Make sure this.hash has a value before overriding default behavior
    if (this.hash !== "") {
      // Prevent default anchor click behavior
      event.preventDefault();

      // Store hash
      var hash = this.hash;

      // Using jQuery's animate() method to add smooth page scroll
      // The optional number (800) specifies the number of milliseconds it takes to scroll to the specified area
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
      }, 600, function(){

        // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
        window.location.hash = hash;
      });
    } // End if
  });
});
</script>
```

this my full template code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



<style type="text/css">
    .wizard {
    margin: 20px auto;
    background: #fff;
}

    .wizard .nav-tabs {
        position: relative;
        margin: 40px auto;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        border-bottom-color: #e0e0e0;
    }

    .wizard > div.wizard-inner {
        position: relative;
    }

.connecting-line {
    height: 2px;
    background: #e0e0e0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 50%;
    z-index: 1;
}

.wizard .nav-tabs > li.active > a, .wizard .nav-tabs > li.active > a:hover, .wizard .nav-tabs > li.active > a:focus {
    color: #555555;
    cursor: default;
    border: 0;
    border-bottom-color: transparent;
}

span.round-tab {
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    line-height: 70px;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 100px;
    background: #fff;
    border: 2px solid #e0e0e0;
    z-index: 2;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 25px;
}
span.round-tab i{
    color:#555555;
}
.wizard li.active span.round-tab {
    background: #fff;
    border: 2px solid #5bc0de;

}
.wizard li.active span.round-tab i{
    color: #5bc0de;
}

span.round-tab:hover {
    color: #333;
    border: 2px solid #333;
}

.wizard .nav-tabs > li {
    width: 25%;
}

.wizard li:after {
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    left: 46%;
    opacity: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    bottom: 0px;
    border: 5px solid transparent;
    border-bottom-color: #5bc0de;
    transition: 0.1s ease-in-out;
}

.wizard li.active:after {
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    left: 46%;
    opacity: 1;
    margin: 0 auto;
    bottom: 0px;
    border: 10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom-color: #5bc0de;
}

.wizard .nav-tabs > li a {
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    border-radius: 100%;
    padding: 0;
}

    .wizard .nav-tabs > li a:hover {
        background: transparent;
    }

.wizard .tab-pane {
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 50px;
}

.wizard h3 {
    margin-top: 0;
}

.header{
    background:#6f6ff4;
    padding:50px;
}

@media( max-width : 585px ) {

    .wizard {
        width: 90%;
        height: auto !important;
    }

    span.round-tab {
        font-size: 16px;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        line-height: 50px;
    }

    .wizard .nav-tabs > li a {
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        line-height: 50px;
    }

    .wizard li.active:after {
        content: " ";
        position: absolute;
        left: 35%;
    }
}
</style>

</head>
<body>

<div class="header">
<h1 style="color:white; text-align: center; font-size: 80px;">Welcome to my website</h1>
<p style="color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;">It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using</p>

</div>





<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <section>
        <div class="wizard">
            <div class="wizard-inner">
                <div class="connecting-line"></div>
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">

                    <li role="presentation" class="active">
                        <a href="#step1" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="step1" role="tab" title="Step 1">
                            <span class="round-tab">
                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open"></i>
                            </span>
                        </a>
                    </li>

                    <li role="presentation" class="disabled">
                        <a href="#step2" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="step2" role="tab" title="Step 2">
                            <span class="round-tab">
                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i>
                            </span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li role="presentation" class="disabled">
                        <a href="#step3" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="step3" role="tab" title="Step 3">
                            <span class="round-tab">
                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-picture"></i>
                            </span>
                        </a>
                    </li>

                    <li role="presentation" class="disabled">
                        <a href="#complete" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="complete" role="tab" title="Complete">
                            <span class="round-tab">
                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i>
                            </span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <form role="form">
                <div class="tab-content">
                    <div class="tab-pane active" role="tabpanel" id="step1">
                        <h3>Step 1</h3>
                        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
                        <br>
                        <br>
                             <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>

                         <br>
                        <br>
                           <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>    
                        <ul class="list-inline pull-right">
                            <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary next-step">Save and continue</button></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane" role="tabpanel" id="step2">
                        <h3>Step 2</h3>
                        <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</p>
                         <br>
                         <br>

                          <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</p>

                          <br>
                          <br>
                           <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</p>

                        <ul class="list-inline pull-right">
                            <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-default prev-step">Previous</button></li>
                            <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary next-step">Save and continue</button></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane" role="tabpanel" id="step3">
                        <h3>Step 3</h3>
                        <p>There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable. If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure there isn't anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text. All the Lorem Ipsum generators on the Internet tend to repeat predefined chunks as necessary, making this the first true generator on the Internet. It uses a dictionary of over 200 Latin words, combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always free from repetition, injected humour, or non-characteristic words etc.</p>

                        <br>
                        <br>
                         <p>There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable. If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure there isn't anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text. All the Lorem Ipsum generators on the Internet tend to repeat predefined chunks as necessary, making this the first true generator on the Internet. It uses a dictionary of over 200 Latin words, combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always free from repetition, injected humour, or non-characteristic words etc.</p>

                         <br>
                         <br>
                          <p>There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable. If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure there isn't anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text. All the Lorem Ipsum generators on the Internet tend to repeat predefined chunks as necessary, making this the first true generator on the Internet. It uses a dictionary of over 200 Latin words, combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always free from repetition, injected humour, or non-characteristic words etc.</p>

                        <ul class="list-inline pull-right">
                            <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-default prev-step">Previous</button></li>
                            <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-default next-step">Skip</button></li>
                            <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-info-full next-step">Save and continue</button></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane" role="tabpanel" id="complete">
                        <h3>Complete</h3>
                        <p>You have successfully completed all steps.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </section>
   </div>
</div>



<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
    //Initialize tooltips
    $('.nav-tabs > li a[title]').tooltip();

    //Wizard
    $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('show.bs.tab', function (e) {

        var $target = $(e.target);

        if ($target.parent().hasClass('disabled')) {
            return false;
        }
    });

    $(".next-step").click(function (e) {

        var $active = $('.wizard .nav-tabs li.active');
        $active.next().removeClass('disabled');
        nextTab($active);

    });
    $(".prev-step").click(function (e) {

        var $active = $('.wizard .nav-tabs li.active');
        prevTab($active);

    });
});

function nextTab(elem) {
    $(elem).next().find('a[data-toggle="tab"]').click();
}
function prevTab(elem) {
    $(elem).prev().find('a[data-toggle="tab"]').click();
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

  $(".next-step").click(function(){
     $(window).scrollTop(0);
  });

</script>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
  // Add smooth scrolling to all links
  $("a").on('click', function(event) {

    // Make sure this.hash has a value before overriding default behavior
    if (this.hash !== "") {
      // Prevent default anchor click behavior
      event.preventDefault();

      // Store hash
      var hash = this.hash;

      // Using jQuery's animate() method to add smooth page scroll
      // The optional number (800) specifies the number of milliseconds it takes to scroll to the specified area
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
      }, 600, function(){

        // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
        window.location.hash = hash;
      });
    } // End if
  });
});
</script>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use animate function

```
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: "0px" });
```

Comment: thank you so much 50% problem has been solved, but i need to put both code (smooth scroll & top scroll  ) together on same page. is it possible